# how to test internal variables

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-design, solidity-0.5.x

I have a contract:

```
contract SS {
  
  address payable commissions = payable(0x...02);
  
  function doStuff() public payable {
    (bool success, ) = payable(commissions).call{value: msg.value * 30 / 100}("");
    require(success);
  }
}
```

How would you test `doStuff` ? Mainly I want to test if the money was taken from user's account as well as if the money went to commissions. `commissions` is like hardcoded and i can't have a function `setCommissions` which changes it.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, `doStuff` is not internal, is public. But the test would be simple

Steps:

1. Deploy your contract.
2. Save the balance of the `commissions` address, lets say you are saving this info on variable `previousBalance`.
3. Call `doStuff`.
4. Now call the balance of the `commissions` address and compare it with `previousBalance`. Something like `expect(await balanceOf(commissions))toBeGreaterThan(previousBalance)`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I might ask one thing: how about testing the user balance (who called the function ? ) seems like it doesn't note the gas costs as well and my tests fail. any idea ?